# ¿Como puedo agregar paginas con diferentes tamaños? FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy intentado tener paginas con diferentes tamaños, por ejemplo que la primera sea letter y la segunda sea legal. Lo intenté con AddPage pero no toma los valores nuevos, se queda con los del constructor.

```
<?php

require_once 'fpdf.php';

class PDF extends FPDF
{
}

// CREACIÓN DEL OBJETO DE LA CLASE HEREDADA
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm',array(210, 260));
$pdf->AliasNbPages();

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    if($i == 0){
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }else{
        $pdf->AddPage('P', array(210, 50));
    }
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Pásanos el código con el que has hecho las pruebas, modificando la pregunta, para poder montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si la respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: No he podido solucionar el problema. No puedo subir la imagen para mostrarle que no me da el resultado esperado

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade la captura de pantalla utilizando el icono de imágenes...

Comment: Ya inserté los resultados

Comment: Modifico mi respuesta para que veas el resultado que obtengo yo. ¿Tal vez sea la versión de FPDF o la de PHP?

Comment: Ya actualicé fpdf y efectivamente se nota un cambio, pero no cambia el alto de la pagina si no el ancho. Se supone que al array se le pasa ancho y alto [ancho, alto] pero cambia es el ancho no el alto

Answer (score 1):

He probado tu código y funciona correctamente. Lo que te está pasando es que no aprecias la diferencia, porque ambas páginas son de la misma anchura, sólo varía su longitud.

Letter: 216 × 279 mm

Legal : 216 × 356 mm

Si muestras las páginas apaisadas, verás que tienen diferente anchura:

```
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'legal');
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'letter');
```

Para el código que propones:

```
<?php

require_once 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

class PDF extends FPDF
{
}

// CREACIÓN DEL OBJETO DE LA CLASE HEREDADA
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm',array(210, 260));
$pdf->AliasNbPages();

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    if($i == 0){
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }else{
        $pdf->AddPage('P', array(210, 50));
    }
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Yo obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Tal vez no estés usando la última versión de FPDF?

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por su respuesta.
Yo cambié los tamaños por unos definidos por mi. Le pase el array con alto y ancho pero no se ve reflejado ningún cambio

Comment: Sí que se aprecia (yo estoy visualizando en Chrome), sólo que la primera unidad es el alto y la segunda el ancho y, efectivamente, la segunda se ve mucho más estrecha que la primera. Tal vez sea que tu visor de PDF escala la página y no te muestra los límites. ¿Qué tal si añades una captura de pantalla con el resultado?